# ParametricPlot with variable range

Tags: plotting

I want to plot a triangle like

[image]

(not exactly, it is a simplified version)
using points `(x,y)` with `0 < x < y` in the range `1<y<0`.
It would be nice if the following works but not.

```
ParametricPlot[{x, y}, {x, 0, y}, {y, 0, 1}]
```

Something close to it can be done by

```
ParametricPlot[{x, y}&&(x<y), {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
```

but I obtain a wiggly triangle.

Do you have any solution?

Comment: ParametricPlot[{y, y - x}, {x, 1, 0}, {y, 0, x}]

Comment: `ParametricPlot[{x y, y}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]`?

Comment: `ParametricPlot[{x, y} && (x<y) ...` I have never seen this syntax. Where did you learn it?

Comment: Are you sure you don't want `RegionPlot` instead of `ParametricPlot`? If not, can you explain why? Additionally: most plotting functions in Mathematica have a `RegionFunction` option which can be used to restrict the plotting region to arbitrary shaped. It is especially useful with `DensityPlot` and similar functions. The arguments it takes are different for each plotting function—look them up!

Comment: @Szabolcs Thank you for the hint, but this is a simplified version of my problem, whose space is not the same as the range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
reg = ParametricRegion[{{x, y}, x < y}, {{x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}}];
HighlightMesh[
 BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[
  reg], {Style[1, Directive[Thickness[.03], Red]], Style[2, None]}, 
 PlotRangePadding -> .1]
```

[image]

```
reg = ParametricRegion[{{x, y}, x < y}, {{x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}}];
RegionPlot[RegionBoundary[DiscretizeRegion[reg]], 
 BoundaryStyle -> Directive[Thickness[.03], Red], 
 PlotRangePadding -> .1]
```

Or

```
ParametricPlot[{x, y}, {y, 0, 1}, {x, 0, y}, PlotStyle -> None, 
 BoundaryStyle -> Directive[Red, Thickness[.03]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! The latter is the direct solution I wanted.